# Math.net check if two matrices are almost equal?

Tags: .net, math.net

Libraries like numpy for python make it really simple to check whether two matrices are almost equal (`numpy.allclose`/`numpy.isclose`). I couldn't find anything similar for math.net. How would I check that two matrices are equal up to a tolerance in math.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found it, [MathNet.Numerics.Precision](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Precision.htm) includes what I was looking for. Works for vectors, matrices, and a whole lot of other data types. Can be used as follows

```
using MathNet.Numerics

var foo =  CreateMatrix.DenseIdentity<double>(3);
var bar =  CreateMatrix.DenseIdentity<double>(3);
var tolerance = 1e-5;
Precision.AlmostEqual(foo, bar, tolerance);
// or even simpler...
foo.AlmostEqual(bar, tolerance);
```

Not sure why I missed it at my first google attempts, but in case anyone else is struggling with this I'm keeping this up.